# Apply timestamp script to multiple tabs in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found this script that I run to give me a timestamp in specific "EditXY" column, when there is a change in "ContentXY" column. I need to reuse it on multiple sheets called: A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4, yet I struggle to figure out how to set it up. What should I change to make it run on every tab (sheet) in this Google sheet?

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT+2";
  var timestamp_format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Address";
  var timeStampColName = "Date Sent";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('A0'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

  var responseArray = ["Edit1", "Edit2","Edit3", "Edit4"];
  var questionArray = ["Content1", "Content2", "Content3", "Content4"];

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRow();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();//get values and place them inside array 
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); //get index position inside the array

 for(var i = 0; i < questionArray.length ; i ++){   
      if (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[1]) > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == (headers[0].indexOf(questionArray[i])+1) ) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!

          var cell = sheet.getRange(index, (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[i])+1) ); 
          var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
          cell.setValue(date); 
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to only change the active sheet you are editing ?

If yes, you simply have to change :

```
var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('A0');

//by

var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
```

But, if you are looking for an editing of all the sheets at the same time you should add another loop.
I give you the idea :

```
var sheets = event.source.getSheets(); // return an array with all sheets in spreadsheet
for (var x = 0; x < sheets.length; x++) {

  var sheet = sheets[x];
  // code for each sheet

}
```